# Suggested method csv data into a tree list

Tags: list, python-3.x, csv, tree

I have a tkinter gui in which there is a tree list widget comprising three columns. I wish to be able to write data in each of these columns. What I'm trying to ascertain is a correct method (if there is such a thing). Is it better to read the csv data, place it into a tree data file e.g.

```
tree_data = [
    ("190127",     "A",         "Assembly"),
    ("191072",     "B",         "Test"),
    etc etc
    ]
```

and then write this into the tree with

```
for item in tree_data:
    self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
```

or

use the csv.dictreader and writing the items directly to the tree list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the second choice. The reason being is that it is cleaner and allows re-usability. If you have to format your csv files into a data set format each time you are adding an extra step to the process.